# My appbar in material ui comes with a default margin wants to overcome this. But margin styling not working for me

Tags: material-ui

navbar:{
color:'blue',
backgroundColor:'white',
height: '80px',
width:' 1152px',
left: '0px',
top: '0px',
borderRadius: '0px',
margin:'0px'
},

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use `disableGutters` prop on your Toolbar to disable gutter padding.

```
<Toolbar disableGutters>
```